# Vite React app works on localhost but not when deployed on Netlify

Tags: reactjs, deployment, vite, netlify

I'm trying to deploy a react app to Netlify by building it from GitHub. It builds fine but doesn't render. Works perfectly in localhost.  The code is

https://github.com/Jimbojuicebox/ai-chat

and deployed site is

https://meek-belekoy-4db97f.netlify.app/

I get error 'Uncaught ReferenceError at index.js' Any help would be amazing.... (edited)

All I can find is references to using require functions but I have none and everything is imported using import.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably one of the packages you've installed is using `require`. Change the vite configuration in the `vite.config.js` file to enable mixed module transformations that way `require` is tranformed to `import` when necessary. ([docs](https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/commonjs#transformmixedesmodules))

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  optimizeDeps: {
    // include: ['linked-dep'],
  },
  build: {
    commonjsOptions: {
      transformMixedEsModules: true,
      // include: [/linked-dep/, /node_modules/],
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: You beautiful person. This fixed it. Thank you!